# How to parse the ksoap2 response returned from web service in android development?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-ksoap2

After the web method is called, a XML string is returned as the response.
the android side code is like that :

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) ws.envelope.getResponse();
```

and the xml is like:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"ID":"leo@gmail.com","float_latitude":22.338,"float_longitude":114.169},          {"ID":"emmy@emmy.com","float_latitude":22.33974,"float_longitude":114.169456},    {"ID":"bob@bob.com","float_latitude":22.3384857,"float_longitude":114.1691},    {"ID":"kay@kay.com","float_latitude":50,"float_longitude":100}]
</string>
```

I want to get

1. the number of id returned
2. save the lat and long with regards to id to my local variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O man. First of all your response isn't XML it is JSON. The way I parse JSON is first build a generic object.

```
 public class yourObject{

  private String id; 
  private double lat;
  private double lng; 
 }
```

From there build out a collection an arraylist should be fine.

```
  ArrayList<yourObject> objects = new ArrayList<yourObject>();
```

After that do some research into JSON here is some starter code.

```
 JSONArray myAwarry = new JSONArray(response);
```

pass in the string that gets returned from the server eg response.

iterate through the array

```
 for(int i = 0; i < myAwarry.length(); i++){
 JSONObject o = myAwarry.get(i); 
 yourObject obj = new yourObject(); 
 obj.setId(o.getString("ID")); 
 obj.setlat(o.getDouble("float_longitude")); 
 obj.setlng(o.getDouble("float_latitude")); 
 //add the obj to the collections of objects
  objects.add(obj);
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: it work perfectly for me! i have searched how to parse ksoap2 xml many times and cant find the solution coz i messed up xml and json. thanks you very much again

Comment: No problem I'm glad I was able to help.